# is there a more elegant way of declaring default variables in a constructor?

Tags: c++

This is what I have. Looks gross.

```
ABC::ABC(std::string newVar1,int newVar2)
{
    var1=newVar1; 
    var2=newVar2; 
}
```

Can this be done on the same line? Something like:

```
ABC::ABC(std::string newVar1,int newVar2):var1,var2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this weird colon-member (" : ") syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Comment: That's informative and answers the question if you read between the lines, but I'm not sold on full dupe. I'm always annoyed at how one of the most useful features in C++, [the Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), is often ignored or glossed over by education material.

Comment: As to doing it on a single line, sure: you can put all that code on one line. But you won’t like it — it’s too hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do:

```
ABC::ABC(std::string newVar1, int newVar2) : var1(newVar1), var2(newVar2) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there a more elegant way of declaring default variables in a
>   constructor?

This would be **initialization** using the constructor.

You can have [*member-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) as follows:

```
ABC::ABC(std::string newVar1, int newVar2)
   : var1(newVar1)
   , var2(newVar2)
{ }
```

> Can this be done on the same line?

You can format the code above in same line.